# How to change the style of this input file

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hi i have this input created in react

```
<span className="btn-file" type='button'>

                  <div style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
                      <span style={{fontSize:'16px'}}>
                          Upload your image
                      </span>
                      <img
                        src={UploadFile}
                        alt="upload"
                        style={{ height: 22 }}
                      ></img>
                  </div>

                  <input type="file" style={{ display: 'none' }} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} name='newAvatar' />
                </span>
```

And i tried to change the style of it, but i can not make it round with the property border-radius, bso i can do nothing, this is the ccs file

```
.btn-file {
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: white !important;
  color: #292D5A;
  border: 10px solid #292D5A;
  border-radius: 32px;
  position: relative;
  width: 190px;
  height: 43px;
  left: -96px;
  top: 125px;
}
```

this is what i got...

[image]

and this is what i need

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment about the way you build your custom file input.

you can use a `span` or a `div` , which both are neutral tag and almost as any others , its `display` style can be reset.

- `span` is supposed to hold only **phrasing** content (text,img,inputs,..) ,
- `div` can hold anything that is block or phrasing content.

---

To restyle your `input` , you can link it to a `label`, so the `label` will catch the click for the `input`  and will let you choose a file to upload .

`input` and `label` are linked via the attributes `id` and `for`  example

```html
<input id="zeInput"type="file"> <label for="zeInput" > click me </label>
```

Now your input can be hidden and the label customized, it will still work.

---

From there you can style either a wrapper holding both `input` and `label`, or just the `label` itself.

here is two example with an icone from fontawsome (replacing your img for tthe demo):

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css);
.inline-box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.customIpF {
  color: rgb(112, 114, 141);
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.customIpF i,
.customIpF img {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.customIpF input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-box customIpF">
  <input type="file" name="filex" id="filex" class="inputfilex" />
  <label for="filex"> 
    <span>Upload your image</span>
    <i class="fas fa-file-upload" ></i><!-- or use an img here -->    
  </label>
</div>
```

or just from the label itself :

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css);
.inline-box {
  display: inline-block;
}

.customIpF {
  color: rgb(112, 114, 141);
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.customIpF i, .customIpF img {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="file"].inputfilex {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="filex" id="filex" class="inputfilex" />
<label for="filex" class="inline-box customIpF"> 
    <span>Upload your image</span>
    <i class="fas fa-file-upload" ></i><!-- or use an img here -->    
  </label>
```

[react jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9zpoeux/)

Answer (score 0):

the element needs to be display:block or display:inline-block

Comment: i already tried that and did not work, do u have another idea?

Comment: I ran your code, and I agree with adding `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;`. Is your code here any different from the one you have in your IDE?

Comment: a span is not supposed to wrap a div, maybe try building this custom input on top of valid html to avoid dealing with unexpected behavior at first ;)